# Jquery UI: stop dragging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to stop dragging the children div when his position is equal or higher than the parent position:

```
$( ".content" ).draggable({
    axis: "x",
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        var wrapper = $(".wrapper").offset();
        var pos = ui.helper.offset();
        $(".content").val(pos.left - wrapper.left);
        if ($(".content").val() >= 0){
            $( ".content" ).draggable( "option", "disabled", true );
       }
    }
});
```

But the div only stops when I release the mouse. I need it to stop while being dragged.

**SOLVED**

```
wrapper = $('.wrapper');
content = $('.content');

wrapperWidth = wrapper.width();
contentWidth = content.width();
startWrapper = wrapper.offset().left;
endWrapper = wrapper.offset().left + wrapperWidth - contentWidth;
content.draggable({
    axis: "x",
    cursor: "e-resize",
    containment : [endWrapper,0,startWrapper,0]   
});
```

Comment: This JSFiddle is just an implementation of the solution provided to have a vision of how to create a draggable carousel with limits hope it helps. // [http://jsfiddle.net/bq7YP/79/](http://jsfiddle.net/bq7YP/79/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe draggable already has the behavior you want. Use the [containment option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) with the array syntax instead of interrupting the drag event.

Answer (score 0):

lets make it easy:

all you need to do is

```
$( ".content" ).draggable({ containment: ".parent" });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/19468/

Comment: Then why not make another invisible child that is bigger than the parent to be the "drag area" and then make your dragable object a child in that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#divDrag" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
<div id="divInvisibleContainmentArea">
div id="divDrag"></div>
</div>
```